# Cannot pass custom Object in an Intent: The Method Put Extra is Ambiguous for the type Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, serializable

If I try to write

```
Car myCarObject=getCar();
Intent details = new Intent(Start.this, DetailsCar.class);
                details.putExtra("Car", myCarObject);
                startActivity(details);
```

Eclipse show me a compilation error **"The Method Put Extra is Ambiguous for the type Intent"** in the line

```
  details.putExtra("Car", myCarObject);
```

If I use the code

```
Car myCarObject=getCar();
ArrayList<Car> parcelableExtra = new ArrayList<Car>();
                parcelableExtra.add(myCarObject);

Intent details = new Intent(Start.this, DetailsCar.class);
                details.putExtra("Car", parcelableExtra);
                startActivity(dettagli);
```

And I try to load the extra with this code in the destination Intent with

```
ArrayList<Car> parcelableExtra = new ArrayList<Car>();
        parcelableExtra = (ArrayList<Car>) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Car");
        Car c=parcelableExtra.get(0);
```

I get this warning

```
12-14 05:30:07.669: W/Bundle(19823): Key Car expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.  The default value <null> was returned.
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1106)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at my.app.com.DetailsCar.onCreate(DetailsCar.java:43)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/Bundle(19823):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-14 05:30:07.679: W/dalvikvm(19823): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
```

And the app crashes with a Null Point Exception

My Car object is Parcelable

so.... what is wrong?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**The first error: 'The Method Put Extra is Ambiguous for the type Intent'.**

The class `Car` is both `Serializable` and `Parcelable`, the compiler doesn't know whether to use `putExtra(Serializable s)` or `putExtra(Parcelable p)` to handle your request. So you have to cast your `Car` to one of them when using `Intent.putExtra()`.

```
Intent.putExtra("car", (Parcelable)myCarObject);
Intent.putExtra("car", (Serializable)myCarObject);
```

**The second error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList**

You put the `Car` object in a `ArrayList` and use `putExtra` to send to the next activity. An `ArrayList` is not `Parcelable` but only `Serializable`. The `putExtra(ArrayList)` works as `putExtra(Serializable)`, but you read it by `getParcelable()`. An `ArrayList` cannot be cast to `Parcelable`.

Comment: In Kotlin:  `myCarObject as Parcelable` or `myCarObject as Serializable`

Answer (score 28):

I use this

**In the sender Activiy**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("my object", myObject);

intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

**In the receiver:**

```
myObject = (MyObject) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("my object");
```

Works fine for me try it. But the object must be serializable :)

Answer (score 13):

This is how I pass my objects which are serializable, I believe it should work the same way for parcelable.
Pass:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(OverviewActivity.this,CarDetailTabActivity.class);         
            intent.putExtra("CAR",myCarObject);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Receive:

```
Car carObject=(Car)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("CAR");
```

Car:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Car implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
......
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** :  implement `Serializable` interface by your class like `implements Serializable`

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent().getExtras()` returns extra `Bundle` from your intent, not your data. To get your list use `getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Car")`