# Intents with extras have a series of params that we don't use - what's their purpose?

Tags: kotlin

From my LandingClass (which contains a ListView called myList), whenever an item from the ListView is clicked, we want to trigger another activity (DetailedActivity), so the code should look like this:

`myList.setOnItemClickListener{ view  ->
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailedActivity::class.java) 
    startActivity(intent)
}`

Now, if we needed to provide additional (extra) info to the Detailed class, such as the position of the element from the ListView that we just clicked, the code would look like this:
`myList.setOnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->
                val intent = Intent(this, DetailedActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("thePosition (text)", position)
                startActivity(intent)
}`

So my question is why in case of sending the extra intent, we need a parent and an id, I don't see them being used anywhere... ?
I don't see some examples in the doc to help me understand. So some questions:

1. What do I need the parent, view and id for?
2. If I click the 3rd element, the position (int) sent I expect to be 2 if the list is 0-index based, right?
3. If I wanted to send a Bundle with more complex information than the position, how would my code (with extra) change? Considering that all params have a defined type, like id is type long. WHat if I wanted to send a paragraph of text instead of the id?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener - the official docs showing the method signature

From my research (see above link) I noticed that:

> parent    AdapterView: The AdapterView where the click happened.

4. Why would we need this? Where is the assignment done, or is it implicitly known?

> view  View: The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
>
> position  int: The position of the view in the adapter.
>
> id    long: The row id of the item that was clicked.

Still this doesn't clarify how to send additional complex info to the DetailedActivity - not a position (int) or an id (long) but maybe an array of complex objects, or a paragraph of text or something else...

Answer (score 0):

Say that your `ListView` contains the headers of some news articles. 
By clicking on a list item you want to be redirected to a details activity where you can read the full text of the article. 
All headers and articles are stored in a `List` of `Article` objects, each containing the header and the text of the article.
How will you identify which article's header was clicked?
This is the purpose of the arguments `position` and `id`. 
Depending on your needs you will choose one or the other, so you will fetch from the `List` the article's text and pass it as an extra to the `Intent` that opens the details activity.
You know that you can create very complex `ListView`s where each item is a container of multiple views or a `ListView` itself. 
This is when you will need the `parent` and `view` arguments.
All this is **application specific**. 
If you don't need it fine, but the arguments are there for you to use if and when you will need them.
Now for:

> If I wanted to send a `Bundle` with more complex information

and

> Still this doesn't clarify how to send additional complex info to the
>   DetailedActivity

This is your responsibility to construct a `Serializable` or `Parcelable` `Bundle` and put it as an extra to the `Intent` and has nothing to do with the available arguments of `setOnItemClickListener`. 
There are a lot of examples here in SO and other sites for serializing objects to put as extras, like
[Cannot pass custom Object in an Intent: The Method Put Extra is Ambiguous for the type Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880396/cannot-pass-custom-object-in-an-intent-the-method-put-extra-is-ambiguous-for-th) 
and 
[How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents) 
Follow the standards and you will be able to send this *complex info* via intent.